# Is the $L_2$-norm squared of a function strictly convex?

Tags: real-analysis

It is known that any norm is convex, thus the square of any norm is convex. It was proven that the squared norm of a vector is stricly convex. Is this property also true for a function. More specifically is the $L_2$-norm squared of a function strictly convex. If so, how to prove it?

Comment: No, imagine $f(x)=0$

Comment: Is your definition of strict convexity just changing the definition of convexity to make the inequality strict?

Comment: Yes, for strict convexity the inequality is met as strict inequality

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true for the squared norm in *any inner product space*.  If $\ x,y\ $ are any two distinct elements in such a space, and $\ 0<\lambda<1\ $, then
\begin{align}
\lambda\|x\|^2+(1-\lambda)\|y\|^2&-\|\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y\|^2\\
&=\lambda(1-\lambda)\left(\|x\|^2-2\langle x,y\rangle+\|y\|^2\right)\\
&=\lambda(1-\lambda)\|x-y\|^2\\
&>0\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Is it true in a normed vector space i.e. a function vector space ?

Comment: Not in general.  The square of the $\ L_1\ $ norm, for instance, isn't strictly convex:
\begin{align}
\|\lambda f+(1-\lambda)g)\|_1^2&=1\\
&=\lambda\|f\|_1^2+(1-\lambda)\|g\|_1^2
\end{align}
for any pair of non-negative functions with $\ \|f\|_1=$$\,\|g\|_1=$$\ 1\ $.

Comment: how abut the L2 norm ?

Comment: A space with the $\ L_2\ $ norm is an inner product space, so the answer already covers that case.